# Javascript File Not Found errors

Tags: javascript

My boss added some custom CSS to styleLibrary/themable and insists those are the only changes made. However, I cannot figure out where all of these errors are coming from:
[image]

I clicked on the "home.aspx:546" error and it showed the following:
[image]

I searched the master page for anything out of the ordinary, and nothing.
The files he added (simply custom CSS files from some company) are:
[image]

Any ideas where the errors are coming from? I realize the ajax and bootstrap CDN URLs are incorrect, but I am not sure where they are to change them. The error happens on every page in the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough information here to really solve the issue.  My guess is that eithe you have a custom masterpage or a CEWP on the page that points to a text file that's in the Style Library or some other location.  If the code in that location used the //maxcdn.... method of referencing the files, instead of https://maxcdn... then SharePoint will often automatically "fix" your url by appending the root host name of the site in your file.  I would first figure out if the modifications are part of the masterpage or if there is a CEWP/SEWP on the page (it looks like the latter but i'm just guessing) and then if it's a CEWP look at the referenced file, or if it's a SEWP look at the code and see if you can see the damaged URLs.

Comment: considering this happens on every page in the collection, it cant be a SEWP or CEWP. I checked the master page and there aren't any script links or cssRegistrations out of the normals

Comment: Then the only other way that I can think of that something would be running on every page in the site collection would be if someone deployed a scriptlink custom action... they can be deployed in a lot of different ways, the easiest ones to find are farm solutions, sandbox solutions, or an add-in... i would look to see if you have any customizations installed in one of those three places.

Comment: It might be an add in, I  didn't think of that